# Converting text to JSON

Tags: json, text, format

How would you recommend converting a text file to JSON format?

I have a text file with about 500 bits of text in the following format:

```
[number in brackets or astriek]
[line1]
[line2]
[line3]
[space]
.
.
.
```

I want to convert it to JSON, like so:

```
"page1": {
   "line1": "LINE1",
   "line2": "LINE2",
   "line3": "LINE3"
},
"page2": {
   "line1": "LINE1",
   "line2": "LINE2",
   "line3": "LINE3"
}
.
.
.
```

Ideas?

Comment: In what language ? Do you have linux tools available ?

Comment: Any language, really. Unix tools and a fully operating terminal at your service.

Comment: Are you aware that your resulting file isn't json ? You need at least `{` at the begining and `}` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Gelatin](https://github.com/knipknap/Gelatin/wiki/).

You'd use a grammar to define your input text (can be a little difficult if you've never done it before). Then you just run your text file through Gelatin with your grammar file, and specify the output.

Edit 1: It would be helpful if you would post a snippet of what you are trying to convert.

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest for me would be do to it in java or go.

**In Java :**

- you can read a file line after line with `readLine` using a `new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))`
- you can fill a `HashMap` of `HashMap<String,String>` during the reading
- create a `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputfilepath))`
- using [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), you then just have to use

this :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(myList, myFileOutputStreamWriter);
```

**In Go :**

You don't need to import an external package, Go includes the needed ones.

This would be something like this (some other error testing would be good) :

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    myBigThing := make(map[string]map[string]string)
    f, _ := os.Open("/home/dys/dev/go/src/tests/test.go")
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)
    var currentPage map[string]string
    pageNum := 0
    for {
        line, err := r.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                log.Println("Error in parsing :", err)
            }
            break
        }
        if currentPage==nil {
            currentPage = make(map[string]string)
            myBigThing[fmt.Sprintf("page%d",pageNum)] = currentPage
            pageNum++
        } else if line=="" {
            currentPage = nil
        } else {
            tokens := strings.Split(line, ":")
            if len(tokens)==2 {
                currentPage[tokens[0]] = tokens[1]
            }   
        }       
    }
    f, err := os.Create("/home/dys/test.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error :", err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    bout, _ := json.Marshal(myBigThing)
    f.Write(bout)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that, though not right away - it seems that I was a bit off to announce "any language" would do - any similar ideas for Linux Bash, JS or Ruby, perhaps?

Comment: I made a complete program in Go... Didn't test it a lot and I didn't code in Go those last months but it seems to work...

Answer (score -1):

Using Visual Studio

If you have the required data in a text file, this will be the best option.

Open Visual Studio and under File menu --> New --> File
Under the installed, you should have the "Web" option. One of the formats listed there is JSON.

Select that and Copy and Paste your text document in VS. Save the file and it is in JSON format.